# Parse lines of output from bash loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, git

I'm trying to parse the output of commands run in a bash loop. Here is an example:

```
$ for i in `git log --format='%H'`; do echo $i ; git branch --contains $i; done | head -n 8
5f11ce7da2f9a4c4899dc2e47b02c2d936d0468e
* foobar
e1c3f6fabd45715b527a083bc797e9723c57ac89
  dev1
* foobar
7053e08775d2c1da7480a988a235e445799cbca5
  dev1
* foobar
```

The command `git log --format='%H'` prints out only the commit ID for each Git commit. The command `git branch --contains $i` prints out which Git branches contain the commit.

I'm trying to find the latest git commit that is not on branch 'foobar'. I would like to echo `$i` for the first branch whose output of `git branch --contains $i` contains a line that does not start with the `*` character, which specifies "current branch". What Bash documentation should I be reading?

Note that I am aware of [other solutions to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git). However, I plan on making additions that the other answers do not account for. Furthermore, this is how I improve my Bash scripting abilities.

Comment: You can achieve what you want in at least 2 ways - by grepping output of `git branch --contains` command or by checking how many lines this command returned with `wc -l`. In either way, you will likely need to use command substitution (you are already doing that but look up on differences between `$()` and backticks), `[` command (type `type [` and then `help [`), `if` or `||` or something similar, and `break` or `exit` to exit for loop.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: Thanks. With `grep -v '^*'` after the `contains` command I can get the name of the branch. Now, how might I output `$i` and break only when grep matches something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might be what you want.

```
for i in $(git log --format='%H'); do
    branch="$(git branch --contains $i|awk 'NR==1{print $1}')"
    [ "$branch" != "*" ] && echo "commit '$i' is in branch '$branch'"
done
```

Prints the commit and its branch if not the current branch.

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure how to use the `[[]]` if in this context though I had found it used elsewhere online. The use of `awk` is creative.

Comment: No problem! The use of double braces here is actually not necessary, and it's a Bash only syntax that's only really required for using Bash regex `=~` or glob comparisons against variables like `case` does with `*`.  I've updated the post to use the single braces which makes it POSIX shell compliant.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm looking at some of your older posts as well to learn some Bash as you give excellent examples. Thank you!